# Socket Connection thorugh Shared Preferences not working

Tags: java, android, sockets, singleton, sharedpreferences

I am creating an android application in which i am creating socket connection in one activity and using Shared Preferences and in another activity I am fetching the socket variables to do furthur jobs but its not working as i am expected

**My question** is **how can i use my exixting socket connection in different actvities** i have searched about it Got some terms like **singltone class,Aysnc task,** But i am not getting it,if singltone is proper way to use socket connetion in different activities then How can i use singlton class in following code please suggest me changes...!!!

Otherwise is it proper way am i doing Shared PRef as following??also suggest some changes!!!

UPDATE: Tagged singlton for suggestions

So here is **First Activity**

```
public class ipInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText ipaddress;    
    String IPADD;
    Integer PORT=null;   
    EditText portnum;
    Button connect_btn; 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy;
    Socket cs = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ipinfo);
    policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    ipaddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    portnum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    connect_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    ip_check();
}

public void ip_check(){
    connect_btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    IPADD=ipaddress.getText().toString();
                    PORT=Integer.parseInt(portnum.getText().toString());
                    try { cs = new Socket();
                            cs.connect(new InetSocketAddress(IPADD, PORT), 2000);
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ipstore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                            editor.putString("ipadd",IPADD);
                            editor.putInt("port",PORT);
                            editor.commit();
                            if(cs.isConnected()) {
                                Toast.makeText(ipInfo.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent inst = new Intent(ipInfo.this,homeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(inst);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }catch (IOException e)
                        {Toast.makeText(ipInfo.this,"Server is disconnected\n",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }catch (Exception e)
                        {Toast.makeText(ipInfo.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                }
            }
    );
}   
}
```

from this activity am fetching values in following activity

```
public class PowerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button restart,shutdown,logof,sleep,abort;
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy;
    Socket cs = null;
    DataOutputStream out=null;
    String SERVERIP;
    int PORT;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_power);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    restart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.restart);
    shutdown = (Button)findViewById(R.id.shutdown);
    logof = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logof);
    sleep = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sleep);
    abort = (Button)findViewById(R.id.abort);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("ipstore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SERVERIP =sharedPreferences.getString("ipadd","");
    PORT=sharedPreferences.getInt("port", 8002);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Working"+SERVERIP+"\n"+PORT,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//this line working fine
    policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    remotecmnd();
}
public void remotecmnd(){
    restart.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //restart code
                        try{
                            cs = new Socket(SERVERIP,PORT);
                            try{
                                out = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
                                out.writeUTF("restart");
                                Toast.makeText(PowerActivity.this, "RESTART SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } catch (Exception ea) {
                                    Toast.makeText(PowerActivity.this, ea.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                        }catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(PowerActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

here is server part code

```
public class serverbackend extends Thread implements Runnable{
public static int SERVERPORT = 8002;
public boolean running = false;
public volatile boolean stop = false;
public Socket client = null;
ServerSocket sc = null;
String value;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    mwcobj = new MainWindowController();
}


@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    running = true;
    try {
        System.out.println("Server Has Started........ \nWaiting for client........");
        sc = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        try {
            while (!stop && running) {
                client = sc.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection Accepted......");
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                value = dis.readUTF();

                switch (value) {
                //Restart the system
                    case "restart":
                        System.out.println("Restarting");
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -r -t 10");
                        break;

                //some extra code
                    default:
                        break;
                } 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Inner try catch "+e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Final try catch error "+e.getMessage());
    }
}


   public void requestStop(){ 
    try{
         stop = true;
         sc.close();
         System.out.println("Server Has Stopped");
    }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Server Stopped "+e.getMessage());}


 }
    }
```

Comment: Remove all StrictMode code lines and try to get it running in a normal way in one activity first. You have to use thread or AsyncTask indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, I created a bluetooth communication app,where I get the same problem,

The answer for the this is to use getter and setter methods. It is very easy to set socket and get socket from other java class rather than sending across activities , If I came across other methods I will definitely will tell you on that..

Using getter setter will work for you I beleive.

```
public class getset
{


    static BluetoothSocket sock;

    getset(BluetoothSocket sock)
    {
        this.sock=sock;
    }


    public static synchronized BluetoothSocket getSock() {
        return sock;
    }

    public static synchronized void setSock(BluetoothSocket sock) {
        getset.sock = sock;
    }
}
```

In the place of using shared preference

```
setSock(socket);  //socket is the Bluetoothsocket which you have to save

Bluetoothsocket socket=getSock(); // to get value from the socket
```

refer https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-you-add-getters-and-setter-in-android-java

Comment: honestly saying i am not getting it.could you make changes in my code with your code part because i dont know where should i place this?? I will appreciate your wokr!!!! thanks

Comment: please point out the lines where you need the socket value ? and also which line you need to pass socket value